# What is the "Character Map" application used for?

Tags: character-set

Ubuntu comes pre-installed with an application called "Character Map". In the terminal, it can be launched as "charmap".

What is this application typically used for? What function does it provide people that Ubuntu sees as so necessary as to include by default in their distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`charmap`** (`/usr/bin/charmap`) is a symbolic link to `gucharmap` (`/usr/bin/gucharmap`); see the output of `ls -al $(which charmap)` in this sense. To understand what is its use, just read its manual page by running `man gucharmap` (or simple `man charmap`) command in your terminal. You will find out that:

> ```
> gucharmap  allows you to browse through all the available Unicode char‐
> acters and categories for the installed fonts,  and  to  examine  their
> detailed properties.
> ```

Comment: Not all installations of Ubuntu come with `gucharmap` or `charmap` preinstalled. I had to install it with `sudo apt install gucharmap`. Installation did not create a `charmap` alias.